# Error for tf.sets.intersection: ValueError: Shape must be at least rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'DenseToDenseSetOperation_12'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've reproduced and isolated my error below. I'm super new to Tensorflow. Is this error occurring because I didn't initialise the idx1 and idx2 variables correctly? If so, what do I have to do?

The error I get is "ValueError: Shape must be at least rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'DenseToDenseSetOperation_12' (op: 'DenseToDenseSetOperation') with input shapes: [3], [3]."

```
import tensorflow as tf

idx1 = [1,2,3]
idx2 = [2,4,5]

intersection = tf.sets.intersection(tf.convert_to_tensor(idx1), tf.convert_to_tensor(idx2))
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
with sess.as_default():
  assert tf.compat.v1.get_default_session() is sess
  print(intersection.eval())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that your `idx` variables to not meet the requirements of the `intersection` method (see the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/rank) for details about the `rank`). As an example, you should not get this error using a two dimensional array:

```
idx1 = [[1, 2, 3]]
idx2 = [[2, 4, 5]]
```